# Why does k=1 in KNN give the best accuracy?

Tags: text, classification, weka, knn

I am using Weka IBk for text classificaiton. Each document basically is a short sentence. The training dataset contains 15,000 documents. While testing, I can see that k=1 gives the best accuracy? How can this be explained?

Comment: K value in K-nearest algorithm is a hyper parameter that needs to decided. There are ways to decide it (see scree plot for KNN), we cant change K value while testing our model.

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying your learner with the same dataset you have trained on with k=1, the output values should be perfect barring you have data with the same parameters that have different outcome values.  Do some reading on overfitting as it applies to KNN learners.

In the case where you are querying with the same dataset as you trained with, the query will come in for each learner with some given parameter values.  Because that point exists in the learner from the dataset you trained with, the learner will match that training point as closest to the parameter values and therefore output whatever Y value existed for that training point, which in this case is the same as the point you queried with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am querying my learner with a test data, not with the training dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The possibilities are:

1. The data training with data tests are the same data
2. Data tests have high similarity with the training data
3. The boundaries between classes are very clear

The optimal value for K is depends on the data. In general, the value of k may reduce the effect of noise on the classification, but makes the boundaries between each classification becomes more blurred.

Answer (score 0):

If your result variable contains values of 0 or 1 - then make sure you are using as.factor, otherwise it might be interpreting the data as continuous.

Answer (score -1):

**Accuracy is generally calculated for the points that are not in training dataset that is unseen data points because if you calculate the accuracy for unseen values** (values not in training dataset), you can claim that my model's accuracy is the accuracy that is been calculated for the unseen values.

If you calculate accuracy for training dataset, KNN with k=1, you get 100% as the values are already seen by the model and a rough decision boundary is formed for k=1. When you calculate the accuracy for the unseen data it performs really bad that is the training error would be very low but the actual error would be very high. So it would be better if you choose an optimal k. To choose an optimal k you should be plotting a graph between error and k value for the unseen data that is the test data, now you should choose the value of the where the error is lowest.

To answer your question now,

1) you might have taken the entire dataset as train data set and would have chosen a subpart of the dataset as the test dataset.
                              (or)
2) you might have taken accuracy for the training dataset.

*If these two are not the cases than please check the accuracy values for higher k, you will get even better accuracy for k>1 for the unseen data or the test data.*